# Positioning the content of a navbar to the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center the content inside my navigation bar to the center. Used the class navbar-center but it does not work as you can see on the code above.

```
    <div class="container">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
           <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Public</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Comercial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div><!--end of div-->
       </nav><!--end of navbar-->
    </div><!--  end of div container-->
```

I also tried the following code on my css but it didn't work either:

```
    .nav{
text-align: center;
}
```

A help on it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
    .navbar{
       text-align: center;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add margin: auto to your .container-fluid element and also specify it's width. You probably don't want it to act that way on smaller viewports either, so you can change it with a media query. [Here's a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelwagner/u9137emo/)

```
.container-fluid {
  width: 493px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Using text-align here wouldn't give you the desired result, if I read you right. text-align would only center the text in it's containing element. In your case - the a tags. Also, if you post some of your CSS, it would definitely help to figure out what's going on.

Comment: In my CSS i have the same code that you sent.
It centers the Links,but not all of them are in the same line. The Contacts link moved one line down.

Comment: @SidneySousa Just adjust (add to) the width of the containing element until all the menu items fit comfortably on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked perfectly.
thank you.

```
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
     display: inline-block;
     float: none;
     vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
     text-align: center;
    }
```